# Camera light stay on after revokes camera permission

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I'm building a camera related application on Windows 8, it previews the camera input on the screen. I'm trying to handle the case that when the user revoke the camera permission ,still the camera's light stay on, it indicates that the camera resource hasn't been fully release.
Please provide a way to dismiss the camera's light when user revokes the permission.